# Bundler Version not AutoSwitching in the Presence of Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, bundler

After upgrading bundler, I am receiving an error of:

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

I have both version 1.17.3 and 2.0.2 installed locally.  I was under the impression based on what I have read that this is supposed to auto switch the version based on what the Gemfile.lock denotes.  This doesn't appear to be happening.

Below is some useful info about my environment.

```
# cat Gemfile.lock 
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    mime-types (3.2.2)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2019.0331)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    pp (0.1.1)
    rest-client (2.0.2)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    terminal-table (1.8.0)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
      unf_ext (0.0.7.6)
    unicode-display_width (1.6.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  pp (~> 0.1.1)
  rest-client (~> 2.0)
  terminal-table (~> 1.8)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
# bundle install
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
# gem list | grep bundler
bundler (2.0.2, default: 1.17.3, 1.16.6)
```

Answer (score 1):

`bundle -v` tells you which one you're using now, and if it isn't 2.0 then you'll get this error.

It's not (yet?) smart enough to load a different version of `bundler` depending on the `Gemfile`. Normally you'd make it mach with `bundle exec`, but you've got a chicken-and-egg problem here then, as that command must succeed before the correct Bundler version can load, but it can't because it errors out early.

Remove all versions of Bundler and reinstall just 2.x.

Comment: Version 1.17 is included with the base ruby install now and it will not allow me to remove it.

Comment: This is also not an option because this docker image needs to be able to handle both versions, as again, bundler documentation says it should be able to.

I have read that it absolutely should be smart enough to utilized a different version of bundler based on the version the Gemfile.lock was created with. https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html#version-autoswitch

Comment: Usually Docker images are focused on one thing, so seeing two versions of one dependency is especially odd. You could try with [RVM gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) if this is a real issue for you.

Comment: This is a docker image that is running in concourse, and is used for our build pipelines.  As such it handles building our ruby projects.  My question is moreso just why this isn't operating as bundler says it should be.

Comment: It's because you can only have one `bundler` command installed at a time. If RVM gemsets doesn't work for you, consider specifying the full path to the `bundler` executable you're trying to engage, like `gem contents bundler` will tell you more.

Comment: If you look at how Travis handles this, they just use the old bundler and you can selectively install the new one with [a `before_install` directive](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/#bundler-20). They have the same problems you do and this is their solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an issue with the ruby docker image we used.  It utilizes the environment variable $BUNDLER_VERSION which overrides the bundler auto switching.  This was solved by upgrading to a newer image.

It could have also been solved by explicitly setting BUNDLER_VERSION to the version needed for the Gemfile.